# DependencyProperties not firing callbacks as expected in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a very simple example of a `DependencyProperty` I've registered on a UserControl which is not quite working as expected.

I am binding this property to a DP (called Test) in MainWindow which seems to be firing the `OnPropertyChanged` events every time it is changed, but the `DependencyProperty` in my UserControl that is the target of this binding only seems to get notified the first time this property is changed.

Here is what I'm trying to do in code:

My UserControl:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCategoriesProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCategories", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnShowsCategoriesChanged));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool ShowCategories
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(ShowCategoriesProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ShowCategoriesProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnShowsCategoriesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this callback is only ever hit once when I expect 3 hits...

        ((UserControl1)d).ShowCategories = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Test = true;  //this call changes default value of our DP and OnShowsCategoriesChanged is called correctly in my UserControl

        Test = false;  //these following calls do nothing!! (here is where my issue is)
        Test = true;
    }

    private bool test;
    public bool Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set
        {
            test = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Test");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Binding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Binding"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"        
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <uc:UserControl1 ShowCategories="{Binding Test}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the `ShowCategories` value to itself:

```
((UserControl1)d).ShowCategories = (bool)e.NewValue;
```

This line is useless, since the value of `ShowCategories` has already been modified. That's why you're in the property changed callback in the first place. At first glance, this could be seen as a no-op: after all, you're simply setting a property value to its current value, which in WPF doesn't raise any change.

However, since the binding isn't two-way, changing the property value **overwrites** the binding. That's why there is no more callback raised. Simply remove the assignment in the callback and you're done.

Comment: Nice catch. I wasn't even paying attention to what the callback does.

Answer (score 1):

Make the binding mode to be `TwoWay`.